# Uncaught ReferenceError: Client is not defined

Tags: discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot to make tickets in a server. I'm using code from a tutorial I found online with a few edits so it works properly. Every time I try to run the code, it says `"Uncaught ReferenceError"`

> ReferenceError: Client is not defined". I've looked for answers on how to fix this, but nothing I've found has worked.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "ticket",
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: "open a ticket!",
    const: Discord = require('discord.js'),
    const: Client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.CHANNEL_CREATE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.CHANNEL_DELETE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.MESSAGE_CREATE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_ALL, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_EMOJI] }),
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
      const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`);
      
      channel.setParent("1001310144359055401");
  
      channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
        SEND_MESSAGE: false,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
      });
      channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
        SEND_MESSAGE: true,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
      });
  
      const reactionMessage = await channel.send("Thank you for opening a middleman request!");
  
      try {
        await reactionMessage.react("");
        await reactionMessage.react("⛔");
      } catch (err) {
        channel.send("Error sending emojis!");
        throw err;
      }
  
      const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
        (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"),
        { dispose: true }
      );
  
      collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
        switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
          case "":
            channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
            break;
          case "⛔":
            channel.send("Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!");
            setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
            break;
        }
      });
  
      message.channel
        .send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`)
        .then((msg) => {
          setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
          setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
  };
  
  Client.login(my_token);
```

Comment: Can you provide any codes you have done so far?

Comment: Uploaded the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.CHANNEL_CREATE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.CHANNEL_DELETE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.MESSAGE_CREATE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_ALL, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_EMOJI] })
```

This two should not be **inside** of your execute. It should be outside. And you make it wrong way. To do it.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.CHANNEL_CREATE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.CHANNEL_DELETE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.MESSAGE_CREATE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_ALL, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_EMOJI] });

module.exports = {
    name: "ticket",
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: "open a ticket!",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
    //Your codes here
}
```

EDIT:

And I also noticed that you're using `const Discord` instead calling the `Client`, I'm pretty sure that you only misspelled it.

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js')
```

Calling the Client, then

```js
const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.CHANNEL_CREATE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.CHANNEL_DELETE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.MESSAGE_CREATE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_ALL, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_EMOJI] })
```

The way you going to get the intents, `const Client` must be `const client`

EDIT:

remove `client` on:

```js
async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord)
```

`async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord)` => `async execute(message, args, cmd, discord)`

Or if you have

```js
const Client = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.CHANNEL_CREATE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.CHANNEL_DELETE, Intents.CHANNEL_UPDATE, Intents.MESSAGE_CREATE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_ALL, Intents.MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_EMOJI] });
```

on your `index.js` file, you dont need to call it again to the another file of your commands.

Comment: It's saying this now: Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Client' before initialization

Comment: See updated answer, and notify the suggested edit, since you're revealing your discord bot token.

Comment: ik the token has been reset so it doesn't matter

Comment: just did what you said, it's giving me this now Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Cannot access 'client' before initialization

Comment: check edit answer

Comment: sorry to be asking so many questions lol, but got another error: ReferenceError: Intents is not defined

Comment: On your `index.js`, line: `const { Client } = require('discord.js')`, just add `Intents` inside of the brackets `{ Client }` => `{ Client, Intents }`